# Memory leak? wiring pi

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I am trying to read out my water meter using a CNY70 and some other components (including a comparator) on the gpio of a Raspberry PI B+. I do this using wiring pi interrupts and switch between rising and falling to deal with the false interrupts. My program contains a strange workaround but seems to work. The only issue is that it takes more an more vmem and stops working after about 10 hours. This is weird since I don't do direct memory management anywhere, and the whole thing contains of 69 lines of code. Is this a wiring pi bug or is there something else going on?

Here is the whole program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void myInterrupt1(void);

void printtime(){
    char buffer[30];
    struct timeval tv;

    time_t curtime;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL); 
    curtime=tv.tv_sec;

    strftime(buffer,30,"%m-%d-%Y  %T.",localtime(&curtime));
    printf("%s%ld\n",buffer,tv.tv_usec);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void callJson(void){
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    int time = tv.tv_sec;
    static int timeprev = 0;

    if (time - timeprev > 1){
        timeprev = time;
        system("./watermeter.sh");
        printf("SEND!!!!\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}


void myInterrupt0(void){
    if (digitalRead(1)==1){
        wiringPiISR(1, INT_EDGE_FALLING, &myInterrupt1);
        printf("rising\n");
        printtime();
        callJson();
    }
}

void myInterrupt1(void){
    if (digitalRead(1)==0){
        wiringPiISR(1, INT_EDGE_RISING, &myInterrupt0);
        printf("falling\n");
        printtime();
    }
}

int main (void){
    wiringPiSetup();
    if (digitalRead(1)==0){
        wiringPiISR(1, INT_EDGE_RISING, &myInterrupt0);
    }
    else{
        wiringPiISR(1, INT_EDGE_FALLING, &myInterrupt1);
    }
//  printtime();
    for(;;){
        sleep(UINT_MAX);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

.watermeter.sh is a bash script that deals with calling the Domoticz API. The whole printtime function was made initially to investigate the problem with double and false interrupts, but this is a known wiring pi issue.

Comment: Interrupt handlers should be short and simple. Calling library functions, e.g. `gettimeofday` and `printf` should be avoided. Calling `system` is unthinkable.

Comment: I know, but it isn't the issue in this case. I just made a version where the only thing the interrupt handlers do is change an integer and the real functions are called in a while(1) loop in main. This version shows (except for the fact that it of course suffers from crippling CPU usage), exactly the same behavior. It eats virtual memory until it is at 3GB, and then stops working.